# Typescript configuration to use modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

I am using typescript for this application, I can't get it to work with modules though. At first I tried with the simple packages installed through npm but I can't work with local modules either, I tried to import both using .js and .ts extension.
I'm given this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

My .tsconfig is:

```
"target": "es2016",
 "outDir": "./src/js",
 "rootDir": "./src/ts",
"module": "commonjs", 
"moduleResolution": "node10", // this one I tried to add to resolve the problem
"esModuleInterop": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"skipLibCheck": true
```

One of the most common solutions, beside changing the .tsconfig file in ways I already did, is to add a exports variable in the script but then I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

The only thing that seems to work is using parcel to bundle the code, but I'd rather work without bundling every change I make

Comment: The [TSConfig Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) documents each option's effect on compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "module" to ES6 (or higher). You have it set to CommonJS; web-browsers do not utilize CommonJS.

The module setting specifies what type of module code should be generated when compiling typescript files.

Comment: I set module to ES2022 and I got it work! Can I ask you what's moduleResolution for? I'm a bit confused